# Loop over javascript object IE8

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, object, for-loop

`data` is an array of Json data
The structure of each object is:

```
var data = [
{
    id: 0, 
    img: "image_src", 
    width: 107, 
    height: 80, 
    shadowBoxLink: "....",
    th: {
        width: 107,
        height: 70, 
        img: "src"
    }
},
{
    id: 1, 
    img: "image_src", 
    width: 107, 
    height: 80, 
    shadowBoxLink: "....",
    th: {
        width: 107,
        height: 80, 
        img: "src"
    }
}
];
```

When I try to access the array in a loop (only happens in IE8, IE7) with:

```
for(var i in data) {
    var imgHeight = data[i].th.height;
}
```

I got an error message: "Impossible to get property of  "height" the reference is null or not defined"

(I translated the message from french: Impossible d’obtenir la propriété  « height » d’une référence null ou non définie)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See edit for another possible issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Accessing array elements can be done more semantically like this:

```
for(var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i ++) {
    var imgHeight = data[i].th.height;
    ...
}
```

[`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops are meant to be used with key-based objects.

**NOTE:** you also have a missing closing quote in your object:

```
th: Object {
   width: 107,
   height: 80, 
   img: "src /* NEED A CLOSING " HERE */
}
```

Comment: @RobW The structure elaborated in the question is the structure of **each object** in the array (`data`); i.e., `data` is an array of objects.

Comment: Thx @Abody97, the quote I just forgot to put it here but it exists in the original code

Comment: I tried the loop you suggested, no errors, but nothing is displayed as well, I'm trying to debug it to see if I have a problem somewhere else

Comment: @vladimire I'm thinking it is a bug somewhere else, since the errors went away.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're looking for the property somewhere it doesn't exist

Make a simple test:

```
for(var i in data) {
  if(data[i] && data[i].th && data[i].th.height){
    console.log('the property exists');
  }else{
    console.log("no, it doesn't")
  }      
}
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the object itself, since the asker said he's only getting the error in IE.

Comment: your approach is correct, but here the problem is different. Please check @Abody97's answer

Comment: I tried you approach, I get 'the property exists' except for the last one ! it's like there is an an empty entry in the array

Comment: Well, yes @Abody97 answer says it all. Since you're using `for in` IE is iterating not only the arrays content but other properties as well and they don't have `th.height` ofcourse. So use `for()` loop

Answer (score 0):

There is an array of objects.

So, use for and get the required object's property.

There is a syntax error in the given code. Close the string with quotes.

Example code is here.

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 0, 
        img: "image_src1", 
        width: 107, 
        height: 80, 
        shadowBoxLink: "....",
        th: {
            width: 107,
            height: 70, 
            img: "src"
        }
    },
    {
        id: 1, 
        img: "image_src2", 
        width: 107, 
        height: 80, 
        shadowBoxLink: "....",
        th: {
            width: 107,
            height: 40, 
            img: "src"
        }
    }
];

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var imgHeight = data[i].th.height;
    alert(imgHeight);
}
```

Comment: but i'm trying to access the property "height" inside th ?